# How to define parametric module in Verilog?

Tags: module, verilog

I have below module in Verilog for imposing delay on a wire:

```
  module DelayModule (input_signal, delayed_signal);
    output  delayed_signal;
    input input_signal;
    wire [16:1] dummy_wire;
    wire [16:1] other = {dummy_wire[15:1],input_signal};
    assign delayed_signal =  dummy_wire[16];
    BUFX12 BUF [16:1] (.A(other),.Y(dummy_wire));
  endmodule
```

I want to make this module such that using an input parameter I can make delay of this module variable according to input paramters. Something like this:

```
module DelayModule (input_signal, delayed_signal,k);
    output  delayed_signal;
    input input_signal;
    integer k;
    wire [k:1] dummy_wire;
    wire [k:1] other = {dummy_wire[k-1:1],input_signal};
    assign delayed_signal =  dummy_wire[k];
    BUFX12 BUF [k:1] (.A(other),.Y(dummy_wire));
endmodule
```

This declaration is not allowed in Verilog but I'm looking for a technique to implement such a thing that a module accepts some parameter like `k` but number of buffers and wire inside module be parameter of this `k` value.
I want to know if I can do such a thing or do something to implement this idea in Verilog or not?

Answer (score 0):

This is allowed only through Verilog parameters (usually implemented as hierarchical parameters passed over to target module in place where it is instantiated). Please note that this would be compile time option so You would not be able to change it during controller operation. Below is code snippet explaining this concept:

```
//----------------------------------------------------
// Module Name: dff_sync.v
//----------------------------------------------------
// Description: conventional 2xFF sync module with parameterizable options
//              such as:
//              - (1) Reset Value - DFF_SYNC_RESET_VALUE
//              - (2) Number of FF stages - DFF_SYNC_NUM_FF_STAGES
//              - (3) Input Bus width - DFF_SYNC_INP_BUS_WIDTH
//
// TBD:
//     - application of random delay (+/- 1 clk cycle), as it is the best evidence
//       of bug-free CDC functinal implementation.
//----------------------------------------------------

module dff_sync #
(
    parameter DFF_SYNC_RESET_VALUE   = 'b0,
    parameter DFF_SYNC_NUM_FF_STAGES = 'd2,
    parameter DFF_SYNC_INP_BUS_WIDTH = 'd1
)
(
    input                               clk,
    input                               rst_n,
    input  [DFF_SYNC_INP_BUS_WIDTH-1:0] data_in,
    output [DFF_SYNC_INP_BUS_WIDTH-1:0] data_out
);

    /* packed dimension */                 /* unpacked dimension*/
reg [DFF_SYNC_NUM_FF_STAGES-1:0] dff_chain [DFF_SYNC_INP_BUS_WIDTH-1:0];

// Note: multi-dimensional array can be accessed as shown below
//       reg [7:0] regA [3:0]
//       regA[unpacked_3_thru_0][packed_7_thru_0]

    genvar i;
    generate
        // iterate through unpacked dimension...
        for (i = 0; i < DFF_SYNC_INP_BUS_WIDTH; i = i + 1)
        begin: g_dff_sync

            always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n)
            begin: p_sync_chain
                if (!rst_n)
                    dff_chain[i] <= {DFF_SYNC_NUM_FF_STAGES{DFF_SYNC_RESET_VALUE}};
                else
                    dff_chain[i] <= {dff_chain[i][DFF_SYNC_NUM_FF_STAGES-1:1],data_in[i]};
            end // p_sync_chain

            assign data_out[i] = dff_chain[i][DFF_SYNC_NUM_FF_STAGES-1];

        end // g_dff_sync
    endgenerate

endmodule // dff_sync
```

And below You can find code that will instantiate variant of this module resulting in 2xFF synchronizer with RESET_VALUE=0, NUM_FF_STAGES=2 and INP_BUS_WIDTH=1 :

```
 dff_sync #
    (
        .DFF_SYNC_RESET_VALUE ('d0),
        .DFF_SYNC_NUM_FF_STAGES ('d2),
        .DFF_SYNC_INP_BUS_WIDTH ('d1)
    )
    i_dff_sync
    (
        // ---- Inputs ----
        .clk      (clk),
        .rst_n    (rst_n),
        .data_in  (data_in),

        // ---- Outputs ----
        .data_out (data_out)
    ); // i_dff_sync
```